# Question regarding comparison of two lists in Python

Tags: python, list, compare

I'm coding a small game for fun where the computer randomly chooses 4 colors as a secret code and the user's job is to guess what they think the colors are, with clues being given based on how close you are to the secret code. When an element in your guess list is a match, the program appends a clue value of 2 to a new list and if the element in your guess list doesn't match the position but occurs in the secret code list, it should append a value of 1 to our clue list.

A problem I'm having is when you compare your list of guesses with the secret code list. Here is an example:

say if the computer secret code is a list with 4 elements as shown: `["Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Red"]`
and your guess is `["Blue", "Blue", "Green", "Red"]`, the program returns a clue list`[2, 1, 2, 2]`. I want it to return `[2, 2, 2]` because I don't want to double count the Blue guess in the guess list when it only occurs once in the secret code.

Here is the code for the function so far.

```
def get_clue(secret_code, guess_list):
clue_list = []    
for i in range(len(guess_list)):
    if guess_list[i] == secret_code[i]:
        clue_list.append(2)
    elif guess_list[i] != secret_code[i] and guess_list[i] in secret_code:
        clue_list.append(1)
    else:
        clue_list = clue_list
print("Your Clue is : ", clue_list)
return clue_list
```

Comment: Look into sets.

Answer (score -1):

The first change I would make is to take out some redundant code:

- The condition of the `elif` can be shortened - we already know that 
  `guess_list[i] != secret_code[i]` if the first if-statement didn't get executed, so we don't need to check for that explicitly.
- Additionally, your `else` branch does nothing, so why even include
  it? You can safely remove that as well.
- I would remove the print statement as well. I wouldn't expect a
  function with a prefix of `get_` to have a printing side-effect. If
  you need to print the contents of the `clue_list`, do that in the
  calling-code once `get_clue` returns.

With these changes, your code looks like this:

```
def get_clue(secret_code, guess_list):
    clue_list = []
    for i in range(len(guess_list)):
        if guess_list[i] == secret_code[i]:
            clue_list.append(2)
        elif guess_list[i] in secret_code:
            clue_list.append(1)
    return clue_list
```

Here's the second round of changes I would make:

- The name `get_clue` isn't entirely accurate to describe this
  function. This function returns a list of clues, so I think a better
  name would be `get_clues`.
- `secret_code` isn't a great name for the first parameter. It's a list
  of secrets. I would either call it `secrets` or `secret_codes`.
- `guess_list` isn't a great name for the second parameter. We can see
  that this object is a list by virtue of the fact that we are doing
  list-like things with it, so don't include "list" in the name. I
  would ditch this nasty habit of including the type of the variable in
  the variable's identifier. A better name would be `guesses`.
- Same thing goes for `clue_list`. We already know it's a list. Don't
  make "list" part of the name. A better name would be `clues`.
- Instead of working with indices (plural of "index"), we can get more
  Pythonic by using `zip` to iterate through both lists at the same
  time.

With these changes your code now looks like this:

```
def get_clues(secrets, guesses):
    clues = []
    for secret, guess in zip(secrets, guesses):
        if guess == secret:
            clues.append(2)
        elif guess in secrets:
            clues.append(1)
    return clues
```

With that out of the way, you said:

> I want it to return [2, 2, 2] because I don't want to double count the
>   Blue guess

<s>Wouldn't you want the `clues` to always have four elements, though? If my guess is 
`["Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue"]`, and `get_clues` returns `[2]`, I have no way of knowing where `Blue` actually is.</s>

You could use a set to keep track of previously made guesses:

```
def get_clues(secrets, guesses):
    clues = []
    previous_guesses = set()
    for secret, guess in zip(secrets, guesses):
        if guess == secret:
            clues.append(2)
        elif guess not in previous_guesses and guess in secrets:
            clues.append(1)
        previous_guesses.add(guess)
    return clues
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response and advice, your example of 4 "Blue" guesses is actually what I intended because you're meant to take multiple guesses, so it would be very trial and error in nature.